# Linear Spaces and Transfomations

Tags: linear-algebra

Let L(ℝ<sup>m</sup>, ℝ<sup>n</sup>) be the set of all linear transformations from ℝ<sup>m</sup> to ℝ<sup>n</sup>. Is L(ℝ<sup>m</sup>, ℝ<sup>n</sup>) a subspace of F(ℝ<sup>m</sup>, ℝ<sup>n</sup>), the space of all functions from ℝ<sup>m</sup> to  ℝ<sup>n</sup>?

This is part of my homework problems. I am not very good at proofs so a coherent explanation is required. Thank you.

Textbook is Linear Algebra with Applications (5th edition) by Otto Bretscher.

Comment: I honestly don't know where to start.

Comment: In general, a linear transformation (in $L(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n)$) is a function $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and all $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ and $f(\lambda a)=\lambda f(a)$. In particular, it is a \textbf{function} from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. It also fulfils certain conditions, but it is nevertheless a function. How about now?

Comment: so L would be a subspace of F because it satisfies (f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x) and (kf)(x) = k(f(x))

Comment: It certainly does satisfies those conditions. It seems you are done. My point was, $L(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n)$ is just a set of functions that satisfy some extra property, so they are certainly functions..

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I over-complicated everything. Didn't realize that it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a linear transformation (in $L(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a function $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and all $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ and $f(\lambda a)=\lambda f(a)$. In particular, it is a **function** from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. It also fulfills certain conditions, but it is nevertheless a function.